# Weird issue with MySql "IN" clause

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a query that have three "IN" clause on the WHERE, the first one is filtering by a string and the other two are filtering by id.

The first in statement looks like this:

```
AND some_table.town_field IN ('Gotham')
```

The other two look like this:

```
AND (some_table.id_field IN(3251, 2531, 5123, [and around 50 more]))
```

Now the bug we are having is that although we have 5 records with "town" = "Gotham", MySql is only returning 3, if we change the first IN clause to:

```
 AND some_table.town_field IN ('Gotham', '')
```

It works well! which doesn't make sense, also if we trim the second and third "in" to only this record id and remove the others, it also works well... I looked at MySql logs and no errors are logged, so it's definitely not a MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET problem.

Comment: Its perhaps the AND is filtering them and getting 3 out of 5

Comment: Can you include the records with the actual data?  It would help interpret what your SQL is actually doing.

Comment: There are only 3 rows where town_field=gotham and id_field blah blah

Comment: @Mihai Actually there are 5 records that have the three conditions, but MySql it's only returning 3 records.

Comment: @MystikSpiral It's a way too large data set to include

Comment: make your condition like `some_table.town_field = 'Gotham' OR  some_table.id_field IN(3251, 2531, 5123, [and around 50 more])`

Comment: We read somewhere that indexed text fields have problems with "IN" clauses, we looked and town_field was an index and a varchar field, so we just tried removing this index and now it's working fine... I'm perplexed

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: MySQL 5.0.4??? That's a BETA release from 2005. Don't you think it's time to upgrade? This sounds related to [Bug #47963 Wrong results when index is used](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=47963), which was fixed in 5.1.41 (2009-11-05).

Comment: We are actually running 5.0.9, my bad... But still, if this bug was fixed in 5.1, it means we still have it. Thanks, we are going to see of updating MySql